# Namespace error

Tags: c#

Namespace error cant find which one?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
 public void CreateNetwork() {
 try {
   Network net = new Network();

   // Creating node "Success" and setting/adding outcomes:
   net.AddNode(Network.NodeType.Cpt, "Success");
   net.SetOutcomeId("Success", 0, "Success");
   net.SetOutcomeId("Success", 1, "Failure");

   // Creating node "Forecast" and setting/adding outcomes:
   net.AddNode(Network.NodeType.Cpt, "Forecast");
   net.AddOutcome("Forecast", "Good");
   net.AddOutcome("Forecast", "Moderate");
   net.AddOutcome("Forecast", "Poor");
   net.DeleteOutcome("Forecast", 0);
   net.DeleteOutcome("Forecast", 0);

   // Adding an arc from "Success" to "Forecast":
   net.AddArc("Success", "Forecast");

   // Filling in the conditional distribution for node "Success". The 
   // probabilities are:
   // P("Success" = Success) = 0.2
   // P("Success" = Failure) = 0.8
   double[] aSuccessDef = {0.2, 0.8}; 
   net.SetNodeDefinition("Success", aSuccessDef);

   // Filling in the conditional distribution for node "Forecast". The 
   // probabilities are:
   // P("Forecast" = Good | "Success" = Success) = 0.4
   // P("Forecast" = Moderate | "Success" = Success) = 0.4
   // P("Forecast" = Poor | "Success" = Success) = 0.2
   // P("Forecast" = Good | "Success" = Failure) = 0.1
   // P("Forecast" = Moderate | "Success" = Failure) = 0.3
   // P("Forecast" = Poor | "Success" = Failure) = 0.6
   double[] aForecastDef = {0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6}; 
   net.SetNodeDefinition("Forecast", aForecastDef);

   // Changing the nodes' spacial and visual attributes:
   net.SetNodePosition("Success", 20, 20, 100, 50);
   net.SetNodeBgColor("Success", Color.Tomato);
   net.SetNodeTextColor("Success", Color.White);
   net.SetNodeBorderColor("Success", Color.Black);
   net.SetNodeBorderWidth("Success", 2);
   net.SetNodePosition("Forecast", 30, 100, 90, 130);

   // Writting the network to a file:
   net.WriteFile("tutorial_a.xdsl");
 }
 catch (SmileException e) {
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
}
```

Network, SmileException and color all have namespace errors?

Comment: Color will be in System.Drawing no doubt, as to SmileException, no idea where that is, sounds custom.

Comment: Are Network and SmileException custom classes?

Comment: how is a namespace error not a question thats ridiculous. Stop flaming! vote to reopen for those new to machine learning and dont have the librarys mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Structural Modeling, Inference, and Learning Engine (SMILE), particularily SMILE.NET.

See http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/wiki/JSMILE_and_Smile.NET

*... teach, not flame ...*

Comment: hey ricky thats correct is smile.net already bundled with visual studio 2010 or do I have to download it?

Comment: You can get the library from http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/

Answer (score 0):

Well, in which Namespace are `Network` and `SmileException` defined?
Go to the class definition and check the namespace...

`Color`is in either in the namespace `System.Windows.Media` or `System.Drawing`. It depends on the parameter of the methods in the `Network`-class.